# How to Customize Cart and Checkout page for Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I noticed when I add to Cart products that have variations, Woocommerce uses 2 templates in Cart or Checkout pages.
if the product has only one or two variations, it uses this template as an example of my product:

```
<tr class="cart_item">
                    <td class="product-name">
                        3-in-1 Rechargeable Trimmer Grinder - CHINA, 3 IN 1 Grooming N5&nbsp;                        
                        <strong class="product-quantity">×&nbsp;2</strong>                                          
                    </td>

</tr>
```

If the product has more than two variations, it uses the following:

```
<tr class="cart_item">
    <td class="product-name">
          Mini Shaver Hair Trimmer Rechargeable&nbsp;                        
          <strong class="product-quantity">×&nbsp;1</strong>                        
        <dl class="variation">
            <dt class="variation-Size">Size:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-Size"><p>Standard</p> </dd>
            <dt class="variation-ShipsFrom">Ships From:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-ShipsFrom"><p>CHINA</p> </dd>
            <dt class="variation-Color">Color:</dt>
                <dd class="variation-Color"><p>White</p> </dd>
        </dl>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

As you notice when there are more than two it uses the class variations.
my question how to modify Woocommerce so that it uses only the 2nd template (more than two variations), in order to simplify code when i want customizing css or javascript.

more details :
review-order.php:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

        if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
            ?>
            <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                <td class="product-name">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                </td>
                <td class="product-total">
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }

    do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );
    ?>
</tbody>
```

cart-item-data.php:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Cart item data (when outputting non-flat)
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-item-data.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.4.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>
<dl class="variation">
        <?php foreach ( $item_data as $data ) : ?>
            <dt class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $data['key'] ); ?>:</dt>
            <dd class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $data['display'] ) ); ?></dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
```

cart.php :

```
<tbody>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

    <?php
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

        if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
            $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            ?>
            <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                <td class="product-remove">
                    <?php
                        echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                            'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
                            sprintf(
                                '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                            ),
                            $cart_item_key
                        );
                    ?>
                </td>

                <td class="product-thumbnail">
                <?php
                $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                    echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                } else {
                    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                }
                ?>
                </td>

                <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                <?php
                if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
                } else {
                    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
                }

                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                // Meta data.
                echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.

                // Backorder notification.
                if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
                }
                ?>
                </td>

                <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                    ?>
                </td>

                <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                <?php
                if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                    $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                } else {
                    $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
                        array(
                            'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                            'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
                            'max_value'    => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                            'min_value'    => '0',
                            'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
                        ),
                        $_product,
                        false
                    );
                }

                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                ?>
                </td>

                <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' ); ?>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="actions">

            <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
                <div class="coupon">
                    <label for="coupon_code"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <button type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>

            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart', 'woocommerce-cart-nonce' ); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
</tbody>
```

wc-product-functions.php :

```
/**
 * Variation Formatting.
 *
 * Gets a formatted version of variation data or item meta.
 *
 * @param array|WC_Product_Variation $variation Variation object.
 * @param bool                       $flat Should this be a flat list or HTML list? (default: false).
 * @param bool                       $include_names include attribute names/labels in the list.
 * @param bool                       $skip_attributes_in_name Do not list attributes already part of the variation name.
 * @return string
 */
function wc_get_formatted_variation( $variation, $flat = false, $include_names = true, $skip_attributes_in_name = false ) {
    $return = '';

    if ( is_a( $variation, 'WC_Product_Variation' ) ) {
        $variation_attributes = $variation->get_attributes();
        $product              = $variation;
        $variation_name       = $variation->get_name();
    } else {
        $product        = false;
        $variation_name = '';
        // Remove attribute_ prefix from names.
        $variation_attributes = array();
        if ( is_array( $variation ) ) {
            foreach ( $variation as $key => $value ) {
                $variation_attributes[ str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $key ) ] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    $list_type = $include_names ? 'dl' : 'ul';

    if ( is_array( $variation_attributes ) ) {

        if ( ! $flat ) {
            $return = '<' . $list_type . ' class="variation">';
        }

        $variation_list = array();

        foreach ( $variation_attributes as $name => $value ) {
            // If this is a term slug, get the term's nice name.
            if ( taxonomy_exists( $name ) ) {
                $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $name );
                if ( ! is_wp_error( $term ) && ! empty( $term->name ) ) {
                    $value = $term->name;
                }
            }

            // Do not list attributes already part of the variation name.
            if ( '' === $value || ( $skip_attributes_in_name && wc_is_attribute_in_product_name( $value, $variation_name ) ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            if ( $include_names ) {
                if ( $flat ) {
                    $variation_list[] = wc_attribute_label( $name, $product ) . ': ' . rawurldecode( $value );
                } else {
                    $variation_list[] = '<dt>' . wc_attribute_label( $name, $product ) . ':</dt><dd>' . rawurldecode( $value ) . '</dd>';
                }
            } else {
                if ( $flat ) {
                    $variation_list[] = rawurldecode( $value );
                } else {
                    $variation_list[] = '<li>' . rawurldecode( $value ) . '</li>';
                }
            }
        }

        if ( $flat ) {
            $return .= implode( ', ', $variation_list );
        } else {
            $return .= implode( '', $variation_list );
        }

        if ( ! $flat ) {
            $return .= '</' . $list_type . '>';
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

class-wc-order-item-meta.php :

```
/**
 * Display meta in a formatted list.
 *
 * @param bool   $flat       Flat (default: false).
 * @param bool   $return     Return (default: false).
 * @param string $hideprefix Hide prefix (default: _).
 * @param  string $delimiter Delimiter used to separate items when $flat is true.
 * @return string|void
 */
public function display( $flat = false, $return = false, $hideprefix = '_', $delimiter = ", \n" ) {
    $output         = '';
    $formatted_meta = $this->get_formatted( $hideprefix );

    if ( ! empty( $formatted_meta ) ) {
        $meta_list = array();

        foreach ( $formatted_meta as $meta ) {
            if ( $flat ) {
                $meta_list[] = wp_kses_post( $meta['label'] . ': ' . $meta['value'] );
            } else {
                $meta_list[] = '
                    <dt class="variation-' . sanitize_html_class( sanitize_text_field( $meta['key'] ) ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( $meta['label'] ) . ':</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-' . sanitize_html_class( sanitize_text_field( $meta['key'] ) ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( wpautop( make_clickable( $meta['value'] ) ) ) . '</dd>
                ';
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty( $meta_list ) ) {
            if ( $flat ) {
                $output .= implode( $delimiter, $meta_list );
            } else {
                $output .= '<dl class="variation">' . implode( '', $meta_list ) . '</dl>';
            }
        }
    }

    $output = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_items_meta_display', $output, $this, $flat );

    if ( $return ) {
        return $output;
    } else {
        echo $output; // WPCS: XSS ok.
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your cart page and remove unwanted code. Without anymore information nor cart page code we can't really help. regards.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i uploaded the post .